# How can I solve black borders in DX9 apps in Windows 10?

Tags: graphics-card, windows-10, directx

Since this PC was updated to Windows 10, this problem started appearing in DX9 applications.  The hardware isn't very powerful (HD 5500) but I've run my games on low settings and on 1280x720 fine in the past on Windows 7.  The monitor's normal operating resolution is 1920x1080.

**Image**:  (red lines added for clarification due to photo quality)

[image: Black Borders, the store for a specific colour of dog]

I've tried World of Warcraft as well, which worked fine at 720p when using DX11, but switching to DX9 on the same resolution immediately caused the same problem, which I feel suggests the problem is a some combination of factors with DX9 as a catalyst.  Tropico 4 exhibits the same behaviour.

I wish I had a larger sample size, but these are unfortunately the only games I have access to at this point on this system.  Sorry.

A few of the things I've tried that haven't seemed to make a difference include updating the graphics drivers, installing the CCC control panel, tweaking its flat-screen settings, toggling GPU scaling on/off, and configuring the scaling type.

Taking a screenshot in-game in the affected applications always results in a screenshot in the proper resolution, so the problem may be a combination of factors with the monitor as well, although I haven't had this problem before upgrading.  When enabling the monitor's built-in resolution notice, it clearly informs me that it isn't in 1280x720, but rather another resolution (unfortunately I'm no longer on-location, and don't remember exactly, but it may have been 1680x??? and from memory it looked like a 4:3-ish resolution).

Comment: What can you tell us about your monitor and display settings.  I don't believe this has anything to do with DX9 specifically.  What I see is a letterbox effect on the application, that tells me, something is adjusting the resolution of the application.

Comment: Thanks, I've made an edit to the question and hopefully provided some additional information. Unfortunately I had to leave, but I can confirm that the Monitor's OSD informed me the resolution was not 1280x720 when using the DirectX 9 applications, although in-game screenshots were.  The screen normally runs at 1920x1080.